# Software to create dynamic flowchart

Tags: diagram, flowchart

I am searching for a tool to create dynamics flowcharts. I know there are several tools to create them generally static but this time I would like to create something that will allow me to use show something in motion. For instance, I want to describe the load balancer mechanism, so if a node will go down, every network packets/requests will be forwarded to the still existing node.

Comment: What OS? Please specify other sw you had tried and does not allow motion.

Comment: For macOs or Windows. I never see Visio able to do that. Am I wrong?